# Dequeue method not correctly deleting elements within queue

Tags: java, queue

My dequeue method currently does not delete the item I wish for it too, instead it deletes the last element from the collection. For example,

If I add in the elements: 1, 2, 3
My toString method will return 1, 2, 3 as expected.

Then when I use my driver to call dequeue, it should dequeue the 0th element, 1 in this case.

Although, the method says "Removed element 1 from the queue" prompting that the `T result` variable has embodied the correct value, although the method does not work as expected, as when calling the toString method after to print the contents, it will print: 1, 2

Then when I call the enqueue method again, on the same queue, if I enqueue the String 3, it will print this as the new queue: 3, 2, 3

I am confused as to where my logic error is, as I assume it is with the extreme case of the collection being filled, but I still run into errors with my dequeue method when the collection is not at max. I attached my code below.

```
public class QueueRA<T> implements QueueInterface<T> {

    protected T[] items;
    protected int front, back, numItems; 
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public QueueRA() {
        front = 0;
        numItems = 0;
        back = 0;
        items = (T[]) new Object[3];    
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return numItems == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void enqueue(T newItem) throws QueueException {
        if(numItems == items.length) {
            resize();
            enqueue(newItem);
        }
        else {
            items[back] = newItem;
            back = (back + 1) % items.length;
            numItems++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T dequeue() throws QueueException {
        T result;
        if(numItems != 0) {
            result = items[front];
            items[front] = null;
            front = (front + 1) % items.length;
            numItems--;
        }
        else {
            throw new QueueException("The queue does not contain any elements.");
        }
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void dequeueAll() {
        back = 0;
        front = 0;
        numItems = 0;
        items = (T[]) new Object[3];
    }

    @Override
    public T peek() throws QueueException {
        T result;
        if(numItems != 0) {
            result = items[front];
        }
        else {
            throw new QueueException("The queue does not contain any elements.");
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void resize() {
        T[] newItems = (T[]) new Object[numItems+4];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            newItems[i] = items[i];
        }
        
        this.front = 0;
        this.back = numItems;
        this.items = newItems;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public String toString() {
        String toReturn = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            if( (i+1) == numItems) {
                toReturn = toReturn.concat(items[i] + " ");
            }
            else {
                toReturn = toReturn.concat(items[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Obviously your resize is wrong... At the first look you are setting front to 0 but copy array as is(without reordering)

Comment: @Selvin The resize should not effect the dequeue method though, in the terms of only having the three elements in the queue, correct? I am not really following how fixing the resize would fix the other errors. Sorry for sounding dumb I just have been at this for a while and still can't nip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your toString() and resize() methods are wrong.

In your example code, you created an arraySize of 3 initially and then added 1, 2, and 3. This occupies all the 3 slots in the array and your numItems is set to 3. The front is set to 0 and back is also set to 0 because after adding 3, your algorithm is:

```
back = (back+1)%items.length;
```

back was initially 2. Now it is calculated as:

```
-> (2+1)%3
-> 3%3
-> 0
```

So your back is 0 at this moment.

Now, when you call dequeue(), the front pops 1 out. So now your array looks like this:

items[0] -> empty

items[1] -> 2

items[2] -> 3

back = 0

front = 1

So, when you enque next and add 3, your enqueue() method checks that number of items in the system is less than size of the array (2 < 3) and adds 3 to the location pointed by back (which is 0 now) and increments it to 1. So, your array looks like this now:

items[0] -> 3

items[1] -> 2

items[2] -> 3

back = 1

front = 1

Now, in your toString() method, without considering the values of front and back, you start from 0 to end:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
.
.
.
}
```

What you need to be doing is start at i = front. if front < back, that means that you travel lineraly from "front" to "back" and print everything. If front > back then you do two loops:

```
for(int i=front; i < arr.length; i++) {
// Code to print arr[i]
}

for(int i=0; i < back; i++) {
// Code to print arr[i]
}
```

This way, it will print from front to end and then from 0 to back.

Also, your resize method is wrong for the same reason. You cannot copy from 0 to numItems, you need to start the copy at "front" and then progress like how I wrote for the toString(). Doing this will ensure that your queue's order is preserved across multiple resizes.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [@Arun Subramanian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64326759/1241334).

Your `resize()` method was simply copying all of the elements sequentially from `items` to `newItems`, then setting `front = 0` and `back = numItems`. Which would have been fine if you had implemented the queue sequentially. However, your implementation of a queue is not sequential, it's a circular / ring implementation. Therefor you have to copy the elements in a circular way.

One way to do this is mentioned in @ArunSubramanian's answer, *"If `front < back`, that means that you travel linearly from `front` to `back` and print everything. If `front > back` then you do two loops."* Another way is to use a do-while loop with modular arithmetic, as in the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void resize() {
    T[] newItems = (T[]) new Object[numItems + 4];
    
    int i = 0; // index used to copy items to newItems
    // do-while used in case the queue is full (i.e. front == back)
    do {
        newItems[i] = items[front];

        // modular arithmetic used to circle back on items
        front = (front + 1) % items.length;
        i += 1;
    } while(front != back);
    
    this.front = 0;
    this.back = numItems;
    this.items = newItems;
}
```

Similarly your `toString()` method can be implemented in the following way:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String toReturn = "";
    
    // need this check, otherwise do-while will illegally access items[0]
    if(!isEmpty()) {
        int len = items.length;
        int i = front;
        
        // do-while used in case front == back
        do {
            String delim = ((i+1) % len == back) ? " " : ", ";

            toReturn += items[i] + delim;
            
            i = (i+1) % len; // modular arithmetic used to circle back
        } while(i != back);
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I was obviously getting stuck on the circular fashion using mod. Your answer helped me understand how its working/how to implement it